# Not getting New Tab in WebBrowser Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two forms `Form1` and `Form2`.

`Form1` has a WebBrowser and `Form2` contains tab code.

In `Form1` on load I have kept the following code to get first tab:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage t = new TabPage();
            Form2 newtab = new Form2();
            newtab.Show();
            newtab.TopLevel = false;
            newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            t.Controls.Add(newtab);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(t);
        }
```

This is working fine.
Now in `Form2` I have a menu item which when clicked will open new tab. Its code is as follows:

```
 public void addTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage t = new TabPage();
            Form2 newtab = new Form2();
            newtab.Show();
            newtab.TopLevel = false;
            newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            t.Controls.Add(newtab);
            Form1 b = new Form1();
            b.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(t);
         }
```

But I don't get a new tab. i.e. When I click the menu item nothing happens.

Comment: `Form1 b = new Form1();` is creating a new instance of `Form1`; you need to get a reference to the *existing* form, not create a new one.

Comment: I tried using Form1.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(t) but as Form1 is not static i cannot use it without creating any object. And you seems right. Now is there any way to do this?

Comment: My Form1 def is like this public partial class Form1 : Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new Form1 in your click Handler, **it is not** the Form1 that you used to create the instance of Form2 in. Your best bet would be to use the [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.110).aspx) method that allows you to set the owning form and as long as your TabControl's Modifier is public it will work. This is IMHO really not the way to go. I would look into creating an event and subscribe to that.

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage t = new TabPage();
    Form2 newtab = new Form2();
    newtab.Show(this);          //note the change here
    newtab.TopLevel = false;
    newtab.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    t.Controls.Add(newtab);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(t);
}
```

This will enable you to do this:

```
((Form1)this.Owner).tabControl1.TabPages.Add(t);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for understanding and giving the answer I wanted. You made my day. :)